# I want to create a program that print the numbers between 1 and 1,000,000 in random order. No number should be duplicated or missed

Tags: java

I want to make a program in Java that generates numbers between 1 and 1 million, no number should be duplicated nor should anyone be missed. I dont know where to start. I cant keep a record of all the numbers i have used, that would be unpractical. How do i do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What part is giving you trouble? How do *you* think you should approach it?

Comment: What have you tried? The only way not having to remember printed numbers, is to pregenerate all numbers and remove the printed ones.

Comment: *" I cant keep a record of all the numbers i have used, that would be unpractical"* Let's see, a million numbers, eight bits per byte, that's 122k to store bitflags for the numbers. Unless you're running in a microcontroller, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the integers from 1 to 1,000,000 in an array list. [Randomly shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) the list and print out its contents.

Comment: Note what the OP said: *" I cant keep a record of all the numbers i have used"*

Comment: He said he can't keep that record, but I'm not convinced without more evidence

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: He said it would be "unpractical". Unfortunately he can not solve his problem without that.

Comment: @igrimpe: I wouldn't be so sure there isn't a cryptographic trick available, but I'm not a cryptographer. Though if we're talking **all** of the numbers, 1 - 1,000,000, I'm not sanguine there is.

Comment: i've used Random, defined min an max as 1 and 1 million respectively,but it duplicates and misses some of the numbers

Comment: @user1859596: Of course it does, it's random. The answer doesn't say *randomly* generate 1,000,000 numbers. It says build an array of 1,000,000 numbers (e.g., in order), then do a random shuffle on it. But of course, that requires doing what you've said you can't do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Could you image **any** PRNG algorithm (be it crpytographically strong or not), that could be configured to return 1..n in random order without misses/repeats? The only one I could imagine: Enumerable.Range(1,n). That works perfect, just that the numbers are not really random ;)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: OP's requirements are open to interpretation. The way I read the "unpractical" bit is that it's pretty hard, given a collection of many numbers, to quickly generate a suitable random number that's not in the collection. I did not read "unpractical" as "we can't store one million integers in memory".

Comment: @NPE: See the CW answer I posted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i have an old pc, my memory is extremely limited, anyway i will give the integer array a try and let you guys know. Thank you for all your help

Comment: @user1859596: If it's a PC, as in an IBM-compatible, you could do this with [the original model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer#PC) from 31 years ago if it had fully-stocked memory slots (256kB), using bitflags. Any "PC" built in the last 20 years just laughs at a 1,000,000 element array in memory.

Comment: The Condition, he wants to solve his Problem sounds really weird.
If He wants to print out the Numbers of 1 - 1.000.000 in a Random order, he should knew the Numbers he has written down yet. Even without writting them in a Random order he has to know about the Numbers he has written yet. But in this case the loop would be the condition of which number has been written yet. So in a short form: not possible

Comment: Technically it only keeps a record of the numbers which have not been used.

Comment: i feel so dumb, you guys are freakin' pros!!! BTW this was a challenge exercise from my teacher, @NPE , T.J.Crowder you guys are awesome

Answer (score 2):

So you need to:

- Output the numbers 1 - 1,000,000 (inclusive)
- In random order
- Without duplicates or repetitions
- Without keeping track of which numbers you've output

This is one of those frustrating questions where the answer is: You can't do that.

So I'll challenge the basis of the question: A million numbers, eight bits per byte, that's 122k to store bitflags for the numbers. Unless you're running in a microcontroller, that shouldn't be a problem. So you should, even in a fairly constrained environment, be able to do something like what [NPE has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13603704/157247).

But unless you can store the numbers, you just can't do it.

*(Made this a CW because I'm just summing up what the community has said in the comments, and because other than "you can't do that" it's just saying "look at NPE's answer".)*

Comment: Let's consider your bitmask approach. How exactly do you propose, on step `n`, to generate a random number that differs from the previous `n-1` numbers? If you know of a method that would give a better than `O(n^2)` overall algorithm, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @NPE: I didn't say it would be fast. :-) I think the requirement is dumb and should be tossed. Without it, yours is quite obviously the best approach. (Not my downvote, btw; I think your answer *is* useful, even though it contradicts the requirements. I also think the question is a time-waster.)

Comment: +1 for **I didnt say it would be fast**. The approach saves memory, not time. If the OP is concerned about memory, it would be the "best" solution.

Answer (score 2):

The one way to do this is to use a pseudo random walk. A simple pseudo random walk uses any large prime (to ensure it has no common factors with the limit) and modulus to wrap the value so that it takes all N values before it repeats.

Here is a smaller example using 100 as the limit and 47 as the prime. You can change this to use 1000000 as the limit and a larger prime like 513239

```
int last = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    last = (last + 47) % 100;
    System.out.println(last + 1);
}
```

prints

48
95
42
89
36
83
30
77
24
71
18
65
12
59
6
53
100
47
94
41
88
35
82
29
76
23
70
17
64
11
58
5
52
99
46
93
40
87
34
81
28
75
22
69
16
63
10
57
4
51
98
45
92
39
86
33
80
27
74
21
68
15
62
9
56
3
50
97
44
91
38
85
32
79
26
73
20
67
14
61
8
55
2
49
96
43
90
37
84
31
78
25
72
19
66
13
60
7
54
1

To make this appear more random you can use a combination of two pseudo random walks.

Comment: +1 way cool. probably not extremely "random", but for some cases "good enough"?

Comment: At the very least, its cheap esp if your limit is a power of 2 as you can replace `% n` with an `& (n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by 'Random'. You could do something like generate random number between 1 to 100 and then say if the random number generated is 52 print current number + 52 and then print all numbers between current number + 52 and keep on repeating till you reach 1 million.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so heres the problem with your request.

From what I read you seem to want to obtain a O(1) where you just do a loop 1,000,000 times. Now the only way to do it by having a very good random is by going back and referencing it from and array that the size of 1,000,000. When you print one out you just make that particular spot = 1 unless the spot is already 1 or something like that. But from what you are saying you dont want to keep a record which will now make your random horrible and almost not even random

See there really isnt anything truly random. There is always a pattern but using certain mathematical operations you can create a pretty unrecognizable pattern.

The problem with the random you would have to use is that is that it would only be able to repeat its self after being printed 1,000,000 times.

This could be done like this:

```
Example randomizing 20 numbers

1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

Now all that is, is num = (num + 2) % 20
```

Now of course you can make the difference larger but the situation is the same. This may look a lot like how a hash map works. But mainly I wanted to point out how this can be done with holding a record and printed in a O(1) but its not a good random at all.